# userId dosen't get into the mongoose schema

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, axios, mongoose-schema

i'm trying to send a post request to create a new task for a user, the mongoose schema of each task is:

```
let todoSchema = new AppSchema ({
    userId: String,
    title: String,
    completed: Boolean
}, {versionKey: false})
```

and when i send the request, the task is created without the userId.
this is the request:

```
add = () => {
        const task = {
            userId: this.props.id,
            title: this.state.title,
            completed: false,
        }

        if(task.title) {
            axiosUtils.create('http://localhost:8000/todos/', task)
            alert('task created!')
        }

    }
```

*the typeof task.userId is string, it is the mongoDB _id of the specific user toString()

Comment: Is "this.props.id" defined at the time of the call?

Comment: yes,  when i run the function with 
console.log(task.userId) it shows the id

Answer (score 0):

The function [axios.create()](https://axios-http.com/docs/instance) just creates an axios instance with the specified config to send requests, but does not actually send any request.
[Here's](https://axios-http.com/docs/post_example) the documentation about how to send a POST request with axios.

Comment: this is not the problem, the request is sent just fine and the new task is created. the problem is the userId, which dosen't get to the task document

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `axios.create()` which is used to create an instance of axios.
To know more about `axios.create()` you can refer the official axios doc:
https://axios-http.com/docs/instance

In order to create a task you need to make a post request like:

```
axios.post("http://localhost:8080/todos/", { taskParam: task })
```

Here the **taskParam** is the name of that variable you are using to accept the task at backend in **req.body** most probably.